# How can I copy 5 folders into 100 other folders?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to copy 5 folders into 100 other folders. I come from the UNIX world so I am trying to accomplish this on a Windows machine. I imagine that this would have to be done in a batch file or possibly even PowerShell.

I have the following file structure:

```
Dir1, Dir2, Dir3, Dir4, Dir5
```

I would like to copy these into each directory:

```
Folder1, Folder2, ... Folder100
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Give it a try and post back here with specific issues that you are having with your code

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Answer (score 0):

For Powershell, it would be just a nested loop:

```
for ($src=1; $src -le 5; $src++) {
    for ($tgt=1; $tgt -le 100; $tgt++) {
        copy-item ("source\Dir"+$src) ("target\Folder" + $tgt) -Recurse
    }
}
```

Often a target might be a variable number, not exactly 100 or could even be a wildcard altogether. In that case you first find all the target folders then copy the 5 source directories to them.

```
Get-ChildItem -path "c:\temp\target" -Filter "Folder*" | ForEach-Object {
    $tgt = $_
    for ($src=1; $src -le 5; $src++) {
        Copy-Item ("source\Dir"+$src) $tgt.FullName -Recurse
    }
}
```